# C# Mifare sector Authentication Code using key B

Tags: c#, authentication, byte, mifare

I'm having a small problem understanding on how the authentication a sector, let's say 12, works and how i can authenticate to it.

The problem so far:
The lack of resources forced me to make the following procedure.

I want to write an authentication code in sector12 in C#, with a key B. The key i wrote with Mifare classic tool, and i made it 000000D2A3, which i dumped with an android phone with mifare card classic tool, on a mifare classic 1k, but i am having trouble sending through the serial port, the authentication string which is in byte... and i have no clue on how to send it, all i know is that i have to send i'm guessing 7 groups of bytes ?!?! The code i write in is .net 2.0 as i want to make it accessible to all types of windows, and most types of readers old and new

Can someone tell me how should it look like ?

And how do i send the "read" command for the block 0 and/or 1 of that sector ?

Thanks

The code i have so far is:

```
try
    {



            byte[] array = new byte[]
            { ?? 0x61, 0xD2,0xA3 };

           SerialPort1.Write(array, 0, 8);
            Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
```

Comment: What transponder are you using? You have to understand transponder protocol and then send to your serial port data that will be understood by transponder.

Comment: I am using a Gigatek MF10R-SK

Comment: Sorry I don't know this one. However you probably need to contact manufacturer support and get RS232 communication protocol.

Comment: I will ask them, but whatever i put in the byte section i get 01 00 15 01 09 76 d0... and this doesn't look any familiar to anything

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually, the bytes it sends it actually calls a stored key in the eeeprom, for that sector. If you store some other key in that sector the command will be the same and the authentication bytes would be the same. This was the missing piece.

There is a different byte code that it is sent to the device and stores the key for that sector, using the 0x61 and 0x60 code for Key b and Key A, for the sector. The device can hold different keys for different sectors